# How to show the file source of Vue 3 warnings in Nuxt 3?

Tags: logging, vuejs3, warnings, nuxtjs3

These are my log outputs

```
[Vue warn]: Directive "ripple" has already been registered in target app.
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected String with value "[object Object]", got Object
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelValue". Expected String with value "[object Object]", got Object
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "provider"
[Vue warn]: Property "Logo" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

However, none of the warnings shows any source file where the warning is related to.

**Not sure why the file is not printed by default**, but it's a **huge time waster** if you don't know where its coming from and you have to **manually look through all of your files.**

**Is it somehow possible to tell Vue to print the file name in addition?**

Comment: My project displays a detailed Vue warning message that identifies the component responsible for the issue without requiring any special configuration. Based on this, I suspect that your project may have a configuration setting that is preventing Vue from showing detailed warning messages. Would you be able to test this by creating a new project and verifying if the default warning settings are working as expected? Alternatively, you could try reproducing the problem on an online tool such as Stackblitz.

Comment: FWIW the causes of problems like these ones can be effectively deduced, narrowed down and searched through the project, possibly with a regex, poor reports aren't the end of the world

Comment: Maybe I should have added that I'm using Nuxt 3 and maybe it is related to the default settings they provide @Duannx

Comment: @EstusFlaskSure thanks. This could be done, but I'd rather prefer a sophisticated solution that lasts instead of hackarounds and unnecessary manual work, especially for things that may reoccur frequently. In the end such things disturb your workflow and cost a lot of time in sum